# How to enter a character to stop a loop

Tags: java

I need to write code that calculates the average of inputs (int) a user has entered. However, the problem is that I also have to allow the user to enter as many inputs as they want and stop when they enter a character(letter).

I can do this problem if there was a given limit I could use, but because the limit could be anything I am having trouble writing a formula that could calculate the average since the number of inputs could be different between any user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AvgGrades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter as many student grades as you like. Enter a character to stop.");
        float total=0, avg;
        int grades = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            grades[i] = input.nextInt();
            total = total + grades[i];
        }
        input.close();
        avg = total/grades.length;
        System.out.println("Average student grade is "+avg);





    }

    }
```

The inputs are:
30.0
45.6
23.8
78.75
90
92
67.5
10.65
88
c
The output should be:
Enter as many student grades as you like. Enter a character to stop.
Average student grade is: 58.477777777777774

My output is that the code just does not run.

Comment: Not only that, but it doesn't compile.  You have ```grades.length``` where ```grades``` is declared ```int``` - not an array.

Comment: Also, your example inputs are not integers, so you don't want to be scanning with ```nextInt```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the process. I'll leave for you the details of turning that into a complete program.

```
float total = 0;
int count = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
    float num = scanner.nextFloat();
    total += num;
    count++;
}
float average = total / count;
```

You don't need to store the individual numbers.

Comment: Incidentally, the terminating non-number is still sitting waiting to be scanned.  If you need it, or to move past it, you can use ```String s = scanner.next();``` to consume it.